# How to make child node follow parent node in Swift 4.2 SpriteKit

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I want to make it so that a child sprite follows its corresponding parent sprite. The child sprite has a physics body which should not mess with the parent's physics body. I have tried to in the parent sprite's subclass to override these functions like this:

```
public override func run(_ action: SKAction) {
    super.run(action)
    physicsSprite.run(action)
}
public override func run(_ action: SKAction, withKey key: String) {
    super.run(action, withKey: key)
    physicsSprite.run(action, withKey: key)
}
public override func removeAllActions() {
    super.removeAllActions()
    physicsSprite.removeAllActions()
}
```

with no success however :(
I'am exclusively moving the parent sprite with SKActions.
The result is that the sprites don't stick together.

```
physicsSprite.zPosition = 10
physicsSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: playerInfo.width+2)
physicsSprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
physicsSprite.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
physicsSprite.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
physicsSprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
addChild(physicsSprite)
```

In this case physicsSprite is the childNode in a SKSpriteNode subclass. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your `addChild(physicsSprite)` inside the definition of the parent sprite? How do you want it to follow and what is actually happening? Have you verified that physicsSprite really is a child of the sprite you want to be the parent?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use an `SKConstraint` object, that describes a mathematical constraint on a node's position or orientation.

From the docs:

> Keep a node within a specified distance of another node or a point in the scene.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skconstraint

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
parentSprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0
parentSprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

physicsSprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1
physicsSprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
```

For more information check [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/about_collisions_and_contacts)

Comment: `categoryBitMask` should not be 0 - this means that the physics body has no category. You may as well not give it a physics body.  You've also set the `physicsSprite` to only collide with itself.

Comment: You can give it a value of 2 instead 0

Comment: Alex - you shouldn't assign categories arbitrarily. You should have a named list of categories in an enum or some other structure and assign the categoryBitMask via a name, not a number.

Comment: The physiBody's bit masks are not the problem.The problem is getting the child node to follow the parent.